# Class field is a non-serializable interface, but its implementation is Serializable. Will it get serialized?

Tags: java, serialization

If I serialize an instance of `Parent` with `field3` being assigned an instance of `MyImplementation`, will `field4` and `field5` be serialized as well?

```
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    public String field1;
    public String field2;
    public MyInterface field3;
}

public interface MyInterface {
    String getText();
}

public class MyImplementation implements MyInterface, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345464324324L;
    public int field4;
    public int field5;

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Should be trivial to verify: create an instance, serialize it, deserialize it, check result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out they will!

PS. Although you'll get a FindBugs warning

> "SE_BAD_FIELD - Non-transient non-serializable instance field in serializable class".

Comment: FindBugs does a >static< code analysis, and will be unable to determine the runtime type of the object assigned to the field ... at the point in time that it is serialized.  From that respect, the warning is correct.

Comment: Yes of course, it is kind of a bad design - it would be better to have `MyInterface` implementing `Serializable` - but then I would get a warning that `MyInterface` doesn't have `serialVersionUID` (which wouldn't make sense). In the end, it all boils down to the fact that marker interfaces like `Serializable` or `Cloneable` aren't examples of a good design...